# Python Django deployment to Heroku H10 error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy API made in Python to to Heroku. I am getting this errors and I do not know how to fix them.

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pythonapisfind.herokuapp.com request_id=a0e39942-e0d5-4159-87fa-b06e997122b6 fwd="217.97.50.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-09T09:06:17.055412+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pythonapisfind.herokuapp.com request_id=b76f9c8c-a187-4516-9338-f01bca9eb726 fwd="217.97.50.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

```
from pathlib import Path
from environ import Env

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

env = Env()
env.read_env(env_file='.env')

SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = env.bool('DJANGO_DEBUG')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'drf_yasg',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',

    'apps.core',
    'apps.offers'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env("DATABASE_NAME"),
        'USER': env("DATABASE_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': env("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': env("DATABASE_HOST"),
        'PORT': env("DATABASE_PORT"),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['pythonapisfind.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

```
asgiref==3.3.1
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==3.0.4
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
Django==3.1.4
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
django-environ==0.4.5
djangorestframework==3.12.2
drf-yasg==1.20.0
idna==2.10
inflection==0.5.1
itypes==1.2.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
packaging==20.7
postgres==3.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
psycopg2-pool==1.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytz==2020.4
requests==2.25.0
ruamel.yaml==0.16.12
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.2
sqlparse==0.4.1
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.26.2
gunicorn ==20.0.4
```

[image]

Comment: can you share your Procfile and settings.py ?

Comment: I've added to original post.

Comment: You share your requirements.txt, add your procfile. The rootcause is generally a problem with the procfile. Btw, your procfile is in the root folder ?

Comment: Yes in root folder.
procfile:
```web: gunicorn offers.wsgi --log-file -```

Comment: this error occur due to improper/incomplete deployment process. your project haven't build and release properly. so when you access URL without build it's throw this error. there are many configurations before deployment and you have to find exact location which break deployment.

Comment: why offers.wsgi ? your settings said WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

Comment: I realised, I changed to project.wsgi , still the same error after pushing master.

Comment: did you check your build log ? Activity / build

Comment: I've added logs image.

Comment: i see a module not found 'backend'. if your local workspace runs, can you try pip freeze > requirements. txt and check if there is no missing import ?

Comment: Whenever I do pip freeze > requirements.txt , an empty .txt file is created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225703/discussion-between-eric-martin-and-stackerss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wsgi.py had a wrong setting for the settings location

Change

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend.settings')
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
```

Comment: Still getting bunch of errors, did it work for you?
```remote:            value = self.ENVIRON[var]
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 673, in __getitem__
remote:            raise KeyError(key) from None
remote:        KeyError: 'DJANGO_SECRET_KEY'```

Comment: Ah yes, write "import os" at the top of settings.py

Comment: Did, I've added an image to original post what it throws in console.

Comment: your secret key should be a value instead of 'DJANGO_SECRET_KEY'